# Arraylist to Array converstion - toArray() function inferred type does not conform to upper bound error

Tags: java

This is the code sinplet:

```
Excel excel = new Excel();
ArrayList<Integer> a1=excel.readExcelSheet("C:\\Users\\Madhukar\\Desktop\\Employee.xls");
        System.out.println("Using Iterator");
        Iterator iterator = a1.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       System.out.println(iterator.next());}
        int x=a1.size();
        int[] a3=new int[x];
        a3=a1.toArray(a3);
```

This is the error message:

> no suitable method found for toArray(int[])
>       method AbstractCollection.toArray(T#1[]) is not applicable
>         (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
>           inferred: int
>           upper bound(s): Object)
>
> ```
>   where T#1,T#2 are type-variable...
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Primitives and generics don't match. You'll need a `Integer[]` rather than a `int[]`.

Answer (score 4):

### Google Guava to the rescue!

To paraphrase [`General Disarray`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_students_at_South_Park_Elementary#Dougie) [*"Google already did it!"*](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/The_Simpsons_Already_Did_It)

If you ever need to do something, somebody at Google probably needed to do the same thing at some time and put a really well tested implementation in Guava.

If it isn't in Guava there is probably a good reason not to do what you are wanting to do.

#### JavaDoc [Ints.toArray()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toArray(java.util.Collection))

> Returns an array containing each value of collection, converted to a
>   int value in the manner of Number.intValue(). Elements are copied from
>   the argument collection as if by collection.toArray(). Calling this
>   method is as thread-safe as calling that method.

```
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ObjectListToPrimitiveArray
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final List<Integer> il = new ArrayList<>();
        il.add(0);
        il.add(1);
        il.add(2);
        il.add(3);

        final int[] ia = Ints.toArray(il);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ia));
    }
}
```

#### If you are leveraging Guava it is better to use an immutable list builder

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    final List<Integer> il = ImmutableList.<Integer>builder()
            .add(0)
            .add(1)
            .add(2)
            .add(3).build();

    final int[] ia = Ints.toArray(il);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ia));
}
```

### Both output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```